# For what reasons can a reference token become invalid

Tags: identityserver4

I have reference tokens which become invalid every time I restart my application

It seems like there are other, seemingly random, scenarios where tokens will be valid for one server and not another. Where can I find this information?

Logs are useless in this case as they simply say "invalid reference token"

and then right below that will say "reference token validation success", same token, different box.

Comment: Do you have an implementation of the `IPersistedGrantStore` interface?

Comment: No I sure don't, and to be clear this happens when my client application restarts, it uses a distributed cache to store client credential reference tokens for 10 minutes. The reference tokens expire in an hour so there's no way that the tokens have expired they just say active: false. And it's sporadic, not always on restart

Comment: Where is your Identity Server hosted? IIS? If so - check the `Advanced settings` of the application pool. There is a property `Idle Time-out` which defaults to 20 minutes and an `Idle Time-out Action` which defaults to terminate. From your comments seems that your token gets invalidated between 11 and 50 minutes (could it be 20<>50?). If your app pool gets terminated (a.k.a. your IDS gets killed) it will restart on the next request, but by not having implemented the `IPersistedGrantStore` you have lost the reference token, because it was kept in-memory.

Comment: We have persisted grants in the operation store (SQL) is this different? And thank you this is a hilarious misstep on my part and I truly hope this is the cause

Comment: I don't know your configuration, but if your IDS instance is killed, and you have not implemented the `IPersistedGrantStore` interface, in the Identity Server project, then this is your problem.

Comment: Does this mean unlimited? And what is the Idle Action?

Comment: yes sir, and idle action is suspend

I believe there is a new default implementation of IPersistedGrantStore because I definitely see reference tokens stored in SQL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170727/discussion-between-m3n7alsnak3-and-chazt3n).

Answer (score 1):

The fact it happens on restart probably means something is being stored in memory. For JWTs it'll be the signing keys, for reference tokens it'll be the persisted grants. As the other commenter asked, do you have a persistent store for said grants implemented?

Comment: No I sure don't, and to be clear this happens when my client application restarts, it uses a distributed cache to store client credential reference tokens for 10 minutes. The reference tokens expire in an hour so there's no way that the tokens have expired they just say active: false. And it's sporadic, not always on restart

Comment: So after 10 minutes the API would go to IDS4 to validate the reference token again and that's what's failing?

Comment: After 10 minutes it will invalidate the cache and get a new token, which will work

However, if I didn't invalidate it at 10 minutes, somewhere between 11 and 50 minutes that token will become invalid before its actual expiration

Comment: Then, the client application will keep trying to use that cached token until it's "expired" but will instead receive a 401 for the next 30+ mintues

Comment: I thought it was only on restart, however that seemed to be coincidence

It appears that it's simply an issue with us caching the reference token in sql